# javascript + handlebars nested #each

Tags: javascript, express, handlebars.js, helper

I am trying to display comments for a photo using nested each but I can't get it to work:

photos: array of {id, description, owner, link}

comments: array of {id, commentText, photoTarget}  //photoTraget is the photo id

index.js:

```
res.render('wall', { title: "Baker's Wall", photos, comments });
```

wall.hbs:

```
{{#each photos}}
{{@index}}: {{this}}
   {{#each ../comments}}
   {{#if_eq photoTarget  @../index.id}}
   <div class="titleR1">{{this.text}}</div>
   {{/if_eq}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

app.js:

```
hbs.registerHelper('if_eq', function(a, b, opts) {
  if(a == b)
      return opts.fn(this);
  else
      return opts.inverse(this);
});
```

**EDIT**

[photo obj screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3SU1.png)

[comments obj screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTQcJ.png)

Comment: Can you reformat the `photos` and `comments` arrays so we can see what they look like? What is the current output?

Comment: @Rastalamm  i added some screenshots. I do not get any output, the condition for if_eq is not met

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues immediately:

First, the way you are accessing the photo's `id` is wrong. `@../index.id` is trying to lookup the `id` property on an `index` Object, one context level above the current. [`@index`](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index) is a convenience variable Handlebars holds the current iteration index when within an `#each` loop. It is a number and so does not have an `id` property. The correct way to lookup the `id` of the photo in the parent context is with: `../id` - which tells Handlebars to step-up one context level and get the `id` property. (Note that the `@` should not be used either. The `@` is a prefix Handlebars uses for its special `@data` variables.

Second, your question states that your `comments` objects each have a "commentText" property, but your template references `{{this.text}}`. If the question is correct, then this should be `{{this.commentText}}` (or just `{{commentText}}`.

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/q03584jv/) for your reference. (Note: I have changed the HTML in the template to make the rendered result more pleasing)

**Optimization**

You may want to consider updating your data structure so that each `photo` object has its own `comments` array. This will make your template simpler as you will not need the `if_eq` helper. Additionally, it will prevent repeated looping through all of the comments. Your current template loops through `comments` once for *each* `photo`. By looping through `comments` once and adding each comment to its respective `photo`, you will save unnecessary iterations when rendering.